# Экспорт mysql базы данных в csv файл. Проблемы кодировки

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, cron

Используя Планировщик Isp manager (cron) я экспортирую таблицу mysql бд в csv файл на сервере. Код выглядит следующим образом
mysql dbname -u user -ppassword -e "select * from table" | tr '\t' ';' > /root/data.csv
Но в полученном файле все русские символы заменяются на знаки вопроса

[image]

Если я правльно понимаю, проблема в кодировке экспортируемых данных.
Можно ли в команду cron добавить правильную кодировку, и как это сделать?
Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: Избавьтесь от CRON и выполняйте операцию только средствами MySQL (event procedure, SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE).

Comment: @Akina Спасибо за ответ. Не подскажите как реализовать ежедневный экспорт посредством mysql? Я понятия не имею как это сделать( Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: *как реализовать ежедневный экспорт посредством mysql?* Экспорт - [SELECT .. INTO OUTFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html), выполнение по расписанию - [Using Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html).